# Add the elements of two dimensional array that have first element same

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have following two dimensional array.

```js
const arr = [
        [56783, 43, 54, 64, 64],
        [65424, 67, 56, 64, 22],
        [56783, 45, 66, 23, 65]
    ];
```

I wanna add the values of internal array with the values of another internal array if both have first element same.

For above example `arr[0][0]` and `arr[2][0]` have the first element **same**, so the result should be like `arr[56783, 88, 120, 87, 129]`. Don't add the first element of internal array, for this example the first element is `56783`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How can we help you?

Comment: feels like he just wants a complete solution.

Comment: you mean `88` as the second element of the result array? Cuz `43 + 45` is `88`?

Comment: @chipcoint Yes, I wanna know, How to do this... I have tried but unable to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with

```
let arr = [
    [56783, 43, 54, 64, 64],
    [65424, 67, 56, 64, 22],
    [56783, 45, 66, 23, 65]
];

for(let element in arr) {
  let firstElement = arr[element];
  for(let innerArrays in arr) {
      if(arr[innerArrays][0] === firstElement[0] && element !== innerArrays){
         for(let i = 1; i < firstElement.length; i++) {
           firstElement[i] = firstElement[i]+arr[innerArrays][i]
         } 
         //You can do this if you want to delete the element that is added to first
         arr.splice(innerArrays, 1);  
      }
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [
    [56783, 43, 54, 64, 64],
    [65424, 67, 56, 64, 22],
    [56783, 45, 66, 23, 65]
];

function solve(arr) {
    var m = {};
    arr.forEach((ls) => {
        var firstElement = ls[0];
        if (!m[firstElement]) {
            m[firstElement] = [];
        }
        m[firstElement] = mergeLists(ls, m[firstElement]);

    });
    var finalLs = [];
    Object.keys(m).forEach((key) => {
        finalLs.push(m[key])
    });
    return finalLs;
}

function mergeLists(a, b) {

    if (a.length == 0)
        return b;
    if (b.length == 0)
        return a;
    var finalList = [a[0]];
    for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        finalList.push(a[i] + b[i]);
    }
    return finalList;

}
console.log(solve(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

```
const arrays = [
    [56783, 43, 54, 64, 64],
    [65424, 67, 56, 64, 22],
    [56783, 45, 66, 23, 65]
];

// TODO: check if anything is undefined (would have to be done nearly everywhere)
//       but thats not what you asked for
let result = [];
let same = [];
for (i in arrays) {
    array = arrays[i]
    for (j in arrays) {
        if (j != i) {
            innerarray = arrays[j]
            if (array[0] == innerarray[0]) {
                same.push([i, j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

// TODO: check for duplicates => [ [ '0', '2' ], [ '2', '0' ] ]
//       inside of same
r = 0;
for (p in same) {
    partners = same[p];
    temparrays = [];
    for (o in partners) {
        temparrays.push(arrays[partners[o]]);
    }
    temparray = [];
    for (i in temparrays) {
        array = temparrays[i];
        for (j in array) {
            if (j != 0) {
                if (temparray[j] == undefined) {
                    temparray[j] = array[j];
                } else {
                    temparray[j] = temparray[j] + array[j];
                }
            } else {
                temparray[j] = array[j];
            }
        }
    }
    result[r] = temparray;
    r++;
}

console.log(result);
```

### Notes:

It has a very bad naming of varaibles and you should add declaration of varaibles (ex.: const, let) everywhere.
It is also not optimised in any way, and i think more complicated than necessary, but it does what you want.
BTW: i just took your text and converted it to code, you already explained what needed to be done.
My `TODO:`'s are there to give you hints how to evolve the code (without any optimizations taken into consideration).